# Can I invoke same system calls with different threads using openmp or pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, openmp, systems-programming

I am working on a testing tool for nvme-cli(written in c and can run on linux).

I am interested in repeating a nvme command 'r' number of times with 't' number of threads.

The below code does the repeat of each command along with threading, but the issue here is the parallel execution time is very much high compared to serial execution.

The reason I found was

```
err = nvme_identify(fd, 0, 1, data);
```

in-turn calls system call ioctl();

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
 for(i=0; i<rc; i++){
          err = nvme_identify(fd, 0, 1, data);
             if (!err) {
                    if (rf->fmt == BINARY)
                            d_raw((unsigned char *)&rf->ctrl, sizeof(rf->ctrl));
                    else if (rf->fmt == JSON)
                            json_nvme_id_ctrl(data, flags, 0);
                    else {
                            printf("NVME Identify Controller:\n");
                            __show_nvme_id_ctrl(data, flags, 0);
                            }
                    }
            else if (err > 0)
                    fprintf(stderr, "NVMe Status:%s(%x)\n",
                            nvme_status_to_string(err), err);
            else
                    perror("identify controller");
```

So can I know how to get true parallelism for this  either with openmp or pthreads?

Comment: System calls are supposed to implement critical sections to deal with multi-threading.

Comment: can I implement critical sections in openmp? can I please get the syntax of doing it(I am new to openmp/pthreads.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can invoke [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) from different threads (otherwise it won't be possible to write programs which do IO on several threads, like most multi-threaded web servers do).

However, some `ioctl` (or other weird system calls) may be blocking or take some long time (several seconds or tenths of seconds) to execute. For a good example, ejecting a CDROM tray is done by some `ioctl` and it takes some visible time (perhaps half a second) to perform (because it is some mechanical action).

I guess that NVME being related to SSD technology, some operations are slow (because the *hardware* itself is slow). Your bottleneck could be the hardware itself, then any kind of parallelisation won't help. It could happen -I don't really know- that you might use the same `ioctl` (on the same file descriptor) in several threads but that the *kernel* would serialize its processing.

When the kernel is doing some blocking or long-running `ioctl` (or any other system call) it uses its scheduler to run other tasks (processes or threads) and do some [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). Then your process is in a `D` state (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and `/proc/self/stat` or `/proc/1234/stat` for process of pid 1234) and don't even handle signals (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) which are postponed.

Comment: So is that i can use pthreads to call `ioct()` with different threads in parallel?

Comment: You can code that way, but I don't know if you win anything. Perhaps some kernel layer is putting some lock. Think of of the CDROM ejection case!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea of what is an nVME SSD (as a hardware visible to the kernel). But I do know that some operations (clearing large parts of the "disk") take many seconds.